# Creating folder under organization using terraform in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have created a folder named terraform and created a service account with owner permission on it. I then used that service account at organization level and provide owner permission.

Now I am trying to create a folder under organization using terraform.

```
# Top-level folder under an organization.
resource "google_folder" "department1" {
    parent = "organizations/70497122"  
    display_name = "department1"
}

provider "google" {
  #project = "terraform-project-0"
  #region = "us-central1"
  credentials = file("c:/terraform/credentials/terraform-day1.json")
}
```

Now as per documention :

```
## The service account used to run Terraform when creating 
## a google_folder resource must have roles/resourcemanager.folderCreator
```

and I am getting the below error in terraform which says about the cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com api to be enabled on project=1003453129743. but there is no project with the project number 1003453129743.

```
│ Error: Error creating folder 'department1' in 'organizations/70497122': googleapi: Error 403: Cloud Resource Manager API has not been used in project 1003453129743 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/overview?project=1003453129743 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
│     "links": [
│       {
│         "description": "Google developers console API activation",
│         "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/overview?project=1003453129743"
│       }
│     ]
│   },
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "googleapis.com",
│     "metadata": {
│       "consumer": "projects/1003453129743",
│       "service": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED"
│   }
│ ]
│ , accessNotConfigured
│
│   with google_folder.department1,
│   on main.tf line 5, in resource "google_folder" "department1":
│    5: resource "google_folder" "department1" {
```

Now solve below questions and creation folder under organization

1. how to assign roles/resourcemanager.folderCreator at organization level to service account.
2. Why is this misleading error "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com service disabled for projects/1003453129743" when there is no project with this number.
3. because of these errors I am not able to create folder under organization using terraform.

I am using terraform1.3.4.exe.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to assign role on organization level , select organization in project selector and then open IAM as shown below

[image]

2nd , in the error its project number and not project id.

[image]

To provide organization access using terraform refer below documentation
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_organization_iam

Comment: Firstly I was not able to fid roles/resourcemanager.folderCreator. secondly you are right that its project number, but the project number referred in the error is not present. in fact, there is only one project present under Organization which has different project number.

Comment: but the main issue is that I am not able to create folder with terraform and getting above said error.

Answer (score 0):

enabling Cloud Resource Manager API resolved the issue.